# Sending mail with devise and Gmail smtp server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, localhost, devise, actionmailer

I am using Devise :confirmable and :recoverable module to confirm a user and to let him recover his password if he forgets it. Everything is going fine, the mail gets generated and I can see it in the server log, but then I am facing errors and the mail is not delivered to the mailbox.
The SMTP settings for my environment.rb file is :

```
require 'tlsmail'
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important shit!
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com', #'localhost', 
  :port => 587,
  :tls => true,
  :domain => 'mail.google.com',  # mail.customdomain.com if you use google apps
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => 'jatinkumar.nitk@gmail.com',
  :password => '_secret_password'
}
```

If the :address is 'smtp.gmail.com' , then i get the following error:

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
```

If i set the :address to 'localhost', then i get the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I don't know what this :address means, a newbie for all this stuff.
On running **uname -a**, i get

```
Linux jatin-ubuntu 2.6.32-24-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 5 09:22:14 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

In my **/etc/hosts** file the entries are :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   jatin-ubuntu

*#74.125.93.109   smtp.gmail.com 
#The above entry added by me*

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

When I uncomment the 'smtp.gmail.com' address in the /etc/hosts file, the following error is gone :

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
```

and now the error is :

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I don't know what is going wrong, googled for the errors and tried everything but nothing came to rescue.
I do have the **'tlsmail'** gem installed and the **'mail'** gem as well, and my application is in development mode.
Help me fix this error so that i can happily continue my rails journey and if possible guide me a little over this :address issue in the right direction so that i understand the basics of this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're still having problems with this try using these settings:

```
require 'tlsmail'    
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,  
  :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port               => 587,
  :tls                  => true,
  :domain             => 'gmail.com', #you can also use google.com
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => 'jatinkumar.nitk@gmail.com',
  :password           => '_secret_password'
}
```

Additionally I would recommend putting these settings in your config/environments/development.rb file instead of environment.rb so that you can specify different mailservers for each environment.

Comment: Thanks man...It did really work. Could you also pen down the settings if I have a domain of my own and a user-name by that domain.?

Comment: Just change domain to be your domain and user_name to be jatinkumar.nitk@yourdomain.com... Everything else should be the same.

Comment: With this settings, will it send email from jatinkumar.nitk@gmail.com to any mailing address ?

Comment: Apparently, `:domain` is [optional](http://bit.ly/QAAPPv), though you wouldn't know that from reading the [docs](http://am.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: After hours of debugging the mysterious `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError error`, this was the only solution that eventually did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is explained here:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336

Other resources:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJZ8w5o_TkE
- http://www.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28480

Comment: @Rio Tera: I am a newbie to all this stuff, so couldn't understand what you are guiding me to. Could you elaborate a bit

Comment: :domain probably should be your domain 'example.com'

Comment: @Rio tera: I don't have my own domain till yet, a newbie to web development. What should i do then?? Is having your own domain a prerequisite for this?? If yes, i will purchase one asap

Comment: please try with :domain => "gmail.com", :username => "jatinkumar.nitk", :authentication => :plain

Comment: @Rio tera : tried "gmail.com" and other things as u said...didn't work

Comment: My last chance to help you: set the :domain to your ip server.

Comment: @Rio tera: Thanks for your help.Tried both machine's local network i/p address and current external (internet) address, didn't work. I am very much confused now, can you guide me to a tutorial for the basics of these things, just to get a clear idea.