# Rails 3/Devise confirmation email server settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I have a Rails 3 app and I'm using Devise for user authentication.  How do I specify an application-wide SMTP server for Devise to use?

I've entered the following into /config/environments/development.rb (Apache2 is set to 8080)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com:8080' }
```

Any ideas on how to get outgoing mail to work with Devise and Rails 3?

Comment: If your ISP provides you with SMTP, find out the address for their smtp server and put that into the `:host` param (e.g. smtp.myisp.com)

Comment: The `default_url_options` config provides the URL for the links in the mail message, not the SMTP server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Devise uses ActionMailer to send emails so you have to configure it.  Take a look at [this tutorial](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) for an example of setting up ActionMailer.  Also if you are using GMail take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232597/sending-mail-with-devise-and-gmail-smtp-server/4404257) for details on setting up Rails 3 to use GMail.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Now Devise is throwing up an "unidentified method" on the confirmation url in the email template.  I posted something to their Google Group so hopefully that will get solved too.

Answer (score 1):

i was just watching episode 206 of the rail cast and seen the answer there `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = 'mydomain.com:8080'`