# How to do confirmation with devise authentication in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am using devise in my application for authentication. When I try to register, I get the following error:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I am using :comfirmable and had uncommented t.confirmable in the migration

Answer (score 11):

In order to use `confirmable` module you need to configure `ActionMailer` that is used by devise for sending confirmation emails. First step for solving your problem is setting up mailer host in you `environment.rb` or in the corresponding file for a particular environment like that:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => “example.com” }
```

For further steps have a look at [this rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445258/rails-3-devise-confirmation-email-server-settings).