# Why am I getting a RunTimeError on Devise for email confirmation when I am signing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, email-validation, confirmation

**UPDATE:**
I have restarted my server among a few other minor fixes and I am not getting the error.  However, I am not receiving confirmation emails.  In addition, I am able to login with clicking on the email validations.

---

While trying to use Devise's email confirmation/validation,
I am getting the following from my server when I sign in to my web app through Devise:

```
RuntimeError in Devise/registrations#create

    Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <p>You can confirm your account through the link below:</p>
4: 
5: <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

This is strange because I have included `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` in my development.rb file and I am in development mode.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write domain in ActionMailer configurations...
The below peace of code should be in developmen.rb file.
Set the domain to 'localhost:3000', restart the server and then sign_up now.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings              = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => "587",
      :domain               => "localhost:3000",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :authentication       => :login,
      :user_name            => "<working email>@gmail.com",
      :password             => "<password>"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not receiving emails,Maybe you havent mentioned gem 'mail' in your gemfile...

Make sure all your configs are correct..see [Sending mail with devise and Gmail smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232597/sending-mail-with-devise-and-gmail-smtp-server)