# ActionMailer 3.2.x OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

I used my Rails app to Rails 3.2.8 and found that my SMTP outgoing mail was no longer able to authenticate with my mail server.

Further investigation revealed that my ActionMailer config was using following:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'mail.mydomain.us',
                                         port: 587,
                                         domain: 'mydomain.us',
                                         user_name: 'xxx@mydomain.us',
                                         password: 'yyy',
                                         authentication: 'login',
                                         openssl_verify_mode: 'none',
                                         enable_starttls_auto:  true,
                                         ssl: true }
```

The specific error message I was seeing was:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232597/sending-mail-with-devise-and-gmail-smtp-server

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue, and I found a couple of things on SendGrids site.

Here is the recommend setup which uses tls and not ssl
http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

If you want to use SSL you should be using port 465

Here are the recommended ports:
http://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/smtp_ports.html